# Want to insert multiple rows from temptable using multiple SET statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

If you look at the code below, I am inserting into the Table from a Temp using 8 SET statements. What I am looking to do is have code present to run through the script and after each execution, change the SET values. I have a list of 2500+ Reversal payments to run. Setting the group of Set statements and running each one separately would take eons. I am hoping someone can help me with a simpler process. Would also be nice to see all of the data that is going to be written before actually inserting.

```
DECLARE 
@C_Id int, @CA_Id int, 
@Event_Type_Code int, @Event_Type_Detail_Code int,
@Term_No int, @OriginalAmount money, @NewAmount money,
@Tran_No int

SET @C_Id = "insert acct # here"
SET @CA_Id = "insert sub acct # here"
SET @Event_Type_Code = 2 -- 2 = Payment
SET @Event_Type_Detail_Code = 13 --12 = positive; 13 = negative
SET @Term_No = 2 --What term is this payment for
SET @OriginalAmount = 1119.55 --Original payment entered
SET @NewAmount = -1119.55 --Reversal payment to negate original payment
SET @Tran_No = 69879237 -- Orig trans we are basing new reversal payment on

Select * from Cortland_Event_Log
where   @C_Id = C_Id 
    and @CA_Id = CA_Id 
    and @Term_No = Term_No 
    and Event_Type_Code = 2 -- Payment
    and Event_Type_Detail_Code = 12 --Positive Payment
    and Message_Completed_Time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Event_Creation_Time


DECLARE @InsertRequest TABLE 
(
[Event_Type_Code] [int] NOT NULL,
[Event_Type_Detail_Code] [int] NULL,
[C_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[CA_Id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Amount] [money] NULL,
[S_Id] [int] NULL,
[SA_Id] [smallint] NULL,
[Tran_No] [int] NULL,
[F_Extracted] [int] NOT NULL,--really boolean
[Retries] [int] NOT NULL,
[Insert_Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Insert_User] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Update_Time] [datetime] NULL,
[Update_User] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Pmnt_Term] [smallint] NULL,
[School_Term_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Message_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Term_No] [int] NOT NULL,
[HT_Event_Id] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO @InsertRequest
SELECT  TOP 1
@Event_Type_Code,
@Event_Type_Detail_Code,
C_Id,
CA_Id,
@NewAmount,--Amount,
S_Id,
SA_Id,
Tran_No,
0, --F_Extracted] [int] NOT NULL,--really boolean
0, --[Retries] [int] NOT NULL,
getDate(),--[Insert_Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
SUSER_SNAME(),--[Insert_User] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
GETDATE(),--[Update_Time] [datetime] NULL,
SUSER_SNAME(), --[Update_User] [varchar](50) NULL,
NULL,--[Pmnt_Term] [smallint] NULL,
NULL,--[School_Term_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
NULL,--[Message_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
@Term_No,--Term_No
NULL--[HT_Event_Id] [int] NULL
FROM TMSEnterprise..CA_Tran_Detl --Fuji..Cortland_Event_Log
WHERE C_Id = @C_Id AND CA_Id = @CA_Id
AND Trans_Amt = @OriginalAmount --If using CA_Tran_Detl in above FROM statement USE "Trans_Amt", If using Cortland_Event_Log USE "Amount"
AND Tran_No =@Tran_No

SELECT * from @InsertRequest  --(Used to view dataset being Inserted)

--Begin Tran
--Insert INTO Fuji..Cortland_Event
--SELECT * FROM @InsertRequest
----Commit
----rollback
```

Comment: Please specify RDBMS

Comment: I apologize. I thought I had that in there. I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Where do the values for your variables come from? This is also a great introduction to set based querying/inserts.

Comment: In the Set statement. So, to process one reversal payment, I would change the SET values to what I need and exectute the script and a Reversal payment would be inserted into the Cortland_Event for processing. I could create 2500+ groups of SET statements, Copying and Pasting each and executing, which is not possible as I am on a time crunch. Hope that helps. I am sorry for my lach of expertise here. Kind of got thrown to the wolves with multiple developers out of the country

Answer (score 0):

I assume the values you need to insert are in an Excel grid (or can be imported into one).  You can use Excel to build the insert sql of each of these rows into the table @InsertRequest.  For example, say I have an Excel grid:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
x    |  y   | z
```

create a column that appends them using a formula like:

```
=CONCATENATE("insert @InsertRequest values ('",A2, "', '",B2,"', '",C2, "')")
```

which will produce:

```
insert @InsertRequest values ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Then cut & past those 2500+ inserts into your script.